# How should the moveForward(lostTime) give the correct output when the hour and minute variables go below zero?

Tags: java, netbeans, hour, minute

I knew the method of delaying by minutes, for instance, from 22:50 to 2:10. I inserted 200 in the parameter of delay method, I am concerned that the method of moving the time forward is not working as I attempted by setting the time 1:20 and moving 100 minutes (1 hour and 40 minutes) forward to 23:40. As I tried to run the code, the output displayed 1:40 after moving the time forward. Which line was wrong in the method of moveForward(int lostMinute)?

```
class Time
{
    private int hour; // between 0 - 23
    private int minute; // between 0 - 59
    public Time()
    {
        this(0, 0);
    }
    public Time(int hr, int min)
    {
        hour = (hr >= 0 && hr < 24) ? hr : 0;
        minute = (min >= 0 && min < 60) ? min : 0;
    }
    public int getHour()
    {
        return hour;
    }
    public int getMinute()
    {
        return minute;
    }
    public void setHour(int hour)
    {
        this.hour = (hour >= 0 && hour < 24) ? hour : 0;
    public void setMinute(int minute)
    {
        this.minute = (minute >= 0 && minute < 60) ? minute : 0;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", hour, minute);
    }
    public void delay(int newMinute)
    {
        minute = minute + newMinute;
        if(minute >= 60)
        {
            // (minute / 60) is an integer division and truncates the remainder, which refers to (minute % 60)
            hour = hour + (minute / 60);
            minute = minute % 60;
            if(hour >= 24)
            {
                hour = hour % 24;
            }
        }
    }
    public void moveForward(int lostMinute)
    {
        if(minute < lostMinute)
        {
            hour = hour - ((60 + minute) / 60);
            minute = (minute + 60) % 60;
            if(hour < 0)
            {
                hour = (24 + hour) % 24;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            minute = minute - lostMinute;
        }
    }
}
```

I saw that delay() is working correctly while moveForward() is not. To make the time notation clearer for sorting, I used `String.format("%02d:%02d")` to indicate the time between 00:00 and 23:59. Please note that I am not using `import java.util.Calender;` or 'import java.util.Date; because part of my project consists of sorting an array by just hours and then minutes. For instance, if we are trying to create the bus terminal project, we assume that the date and calendar do not matter in schedule.

```
public class MainTime
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Time t1 = new Time(23:50);
        Time t2 = new Time(1:20);
        Time t3 = new Time(4:50);
        Time t4 = new Time(18:30);
        Time t5 = new Time(14:15);
        t1.delay(200);
        t2.moveForward(100);
        t3.delay(100);
        t4.moveForward(20);
        t5.moveForward(160);
        System.out.println(t1.toString());
        System.out.println(t2.toString());
        System.out.println(t3.toString());
        System.out.println(t4.toString());
        System.out.println(t5.toString());
    }
}
```

The constraints are when the change in time is greater than the minute in parameter and when the hour is going to zero. When I ran the code in NetBeans, `t1` had 2:10 when I added 200 into 23:50 in `delay(newMinute)` method; `t2` had 1:40 when I subtracted 100 from 1:20 in `moveForward(lostMinute)` method; `t3` had 6:30 when I added 100 into 4:50 in `delay(newMinute)`; `t4` had 18:10 when I subtracted 20 from 18:30 in `moveForward(lostMinute)`; `t5` had 14:-25 when I subtracted 160 from 14:15 in `moveForward(lostMinute)`. The variables `t2` and `t5` after execution should actually be 23:40 and 11:35, respectively.
Please determine which lines in `public void moveForward(int lostMinute)` make the improper output after subtracting the minutes from given time. 
In case the minute goes to zero, 60 and modulo notation `%` could be useful; in case the hour goes to zero, 24 and modulo notation `%` could be useful. I hope for the `moveForward(lostMinute)` to work well in the cases when `minute < 0` and when `hour < 0`.

Comment: Sidenote: You are aware of the [Date and Time Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html)? Using those over reinventing the wheel should be an improvement.

Comment: I am using the time only, not the date, in hours and minutes. My group project I am working on right now consists of queue and sorting algorithm, the latter of which involves in comparison by the departure or arrival time of the bus in hours and then in minutes. I assume that the date and calendar are negligible for the time class I posted just now.

Comment: Well that's exactly what the `LocalTime` class is for... deals with time but not with date. I mean it's up to you but consider using the library functions as those tend to be implemented without fault.

Comment: I certainly recommend `LocalTime` too. And its `plusMinutes` and `minusMinutes` methods’ calculations wrap around midnight.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

```
    LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.of(23, 50);
    t1 = t1.plusMinutes(200);
    System.out.println(t1.toString()); // 03:10

    LocalTime t2 = LocalTime.of(1, 20);
    t2 = t2.minusMinutes(100);
    System.out.println(t2.toString()); // 23:40

    LocalTime t3 = LocalTime.of(4, 50);
    t3 = t3.plusMinutes(100);
    System.out.println(t3.toString()); // 06:30

    LocalTime t4 = LocalTime.of(18, 30);
    t4 = t4.minusMinutes(20);
    System.out.println(t4.toString()); // 18:10

    LocalTime t5 = LocalTime.of(14, 15);
    t5 = t5.minusMinutes(160);
    System.out.println(t5.toString()); // 11:35
```

Output is given as comments. I think it is what you wanted. So don’t reinvent the wheel. Instead of rolling your own `Time` class, use `LocalTime`. It’s there for you to use, it has been developed and tested for you. `LocalTime` is a time of day in the interval from 00:00 to 23:59:59.999999999. Except that it include seconds and fraction of second it coincides with your interval. If you never set the seconds to something other than 0, they won’t be printed through the `toString` method. Also `LocalTime` implements `Comparable`, so sorting is straightforward.

Be aware that a `LocalTime` object is immutable, so instead of mutator methods it has methods that return a new `LocalTime` object with the new value. This is already demonstrated with `plusMinutes` and `minusMinutes` above. Also instead of `myLocalTime.setHour(17);` you need `myLocalTime = myLocalTime.withHour(17);`, etc.

### What went wrong in your code?

Your `moveForward` method seems to be handling the *hour* correctly in the case where it is to be moved back to the previous hour, for example from 14:05 to 13:55 or from 14:55 to 13:05. In this case you are never subtracting `lostMinutes`, which I think you should somehow. When `minute` is 0–59, then `((60 + minute) / 60)` will always be 1, so you are always subtracting exactly 1 hour, never 2 or more.

Genrally the expected ranges of the arguments to both `delay` and `moveForward` are unclear. I think they should have been documented and the arguments validated against the documented limits.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.